# Wide to long, inconsistent column names

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the following dataframe, which you can get as a CSV here: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c4d94fd3a7dc43e3ec249bff373a0082/data.csv

My colnames, are as follows. As you can see, the names are not sequential (for example, Q1 is missing, no Q3 or Q4, and so on). I need to keep it that way. Check that some cases have an additional ".1" that is irrelevant.

```
  [1] "Q2_1"     "Q2_2"     "Q5_1"     "Q5_2"     "Q6_1"     "Q6_2"     "Q9_1"     "Q9_2"     "Q11_1"    "Q11_2"    "Q8_1"     "Q8_2"     "Q14_1"   
 [14] "Q14_2"    "Q16_1"    "Q16_2"    "Q10_1"    "Q10_2"    "Q11_1.1"  "Q11_2.1"  "Q19_1"    "Q19_2"    "Q20_1"    "Q20_2"    "Q21_1"    "Q21_2"   
 [27] "Q15_1"    "Q15_2"    "Q23_1"    "Q23_2"    "Q24_1"    "Q24_2"    "Q25_1"    "Q25_2"    "Q26_1"    "Q26_2"    "Q20_1.1"  "Q20_2.1"  "Q21_1.1" 
 [40] "Q21_2.1"  "Q29_1"    "Q29_2"    "Q30_1"    "Q30_2"    "Q35_1"    "Q35_2"    "Q36_1"    "Q36_2"    "Q37_1"    "Q37_2"    "Q38_1"    "Q38_2"   
 [53] "Q39_1"    "Q39_2"    "Q41_1"    "Q41_2"    "Q30_1.1"  "Q30_2.1"  "Q43_1"    "Q43_2"    "Q44_1"    "Q44_2"    "Q45_1"    "Q45_2"    "Q47_1"   
 [66] "Q47_2"    "Q48_1"    "Q48_2"    "Q36_1.1"  "Q36_2.1"  "Q37_1.1"  "Q37_2.1"  "Q51_1"    "Q51_2"    "Q52_1"    "Q52_2"    "Q53_1"    "Q53_2"   
 [79] "Q41_1.1"  "Q41_2.1"  "Q42_1"    "Q42_2"    "Q56_1"    "Q56_2"    "Q57_1"    "Q57_2"    "Q58_1"    "Q58_2"    "Q59_1"    "Q59_2"    "Q60_1"   
 [92] "Q60_2"    "Q61_1"    "Q61_2"    "Q62_1"    "Q62_2"    "Q63_1"    "Q63_2"    "Q64_1"    "Q64_2"    "Q65_1"    "Q65_2"    "Q53_1.1"  "Q53_2.1" 
[105] "Q54_1"    "Q54_2"    "Q68_1"    "Q68_2"    "Q75_1"    "Q75_2"    "Q57_1.1"  "Q57_2.1"  "Q58_1.1"  "Q58_2.1"  "Q59_1.1"  "Q59_2.1"  "Q60_1.1" 
[118] "Q60_2.1"  "Q61_1.1"  "Q61_2.1"  "Q81_1"    "Q81_2"    "Q82_1"    "Q82_2"    "Q83_1"    "Q83_2"    "Q87_1"    "Q87_2"    "Q88_1"    "Q88_2"   
[131] "Q89_1"    "Q89_2"    "Q90_1"    "Q90_2"    "Q91_1"    "Q91_2"    "Q92_1"    "Q92_2"    "Q93_1"    "Q93_2"    "Q94_1"    "Q94_2"    "Q95_1"   
[144] "Q95_2"    "Q74_1"    "Q74_2"    "Q75_1.1"  "Q75_2.1"  "Q76_1"    "Q76_2"    "Q77_1"    "Q77_2"    "Q100_1"   "Q100_2"   "Q101_1"   "Q101_2"  
[157] "Q102_1"   "Q102_2"   "Q103_1"   "Q103_2"   "Q104_1"   "Q104_2"   "Q105_1"   "Q105_2"   "Q106_1"   "Q106_2"   "Q107_1"   "Q107_2"   "Q108_1"  
[170] "Q108_2"   "Q113_1"   "Q113_2"   "Q114_1"   "Q114_2"   "Q117_1"   "Q117_2"   "Q96_1"    "Q96_2"    "Q97_1"    "Q97_2"    "Q98_1"    "Q98_2"   
[183] "Q121_1"   "Q121_2"   "Q103_1.1" "Q103_2.1" "Q104_1.1" "Q104_2.1" "Q127_1"   "Q127_2"   "Q128_1"   "Q128_2"   "Q129_1"   "Q129_2"
```

**QUESTION:** I need to convert this from WIDE to LONG, to obtain something as:

```
QUESTION CASE VALUE
Q2        1     5
Q2        2     5
Q5        1     1
Q5        2     2
```

I have tried to reshape as follows but keep getting the varying error, and I'm not sure I'm splitting this correctly either:

```
test <- reshape(data, sep = "_", times = c(1, 2), direction = "long", varying = colnames(data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` form **tidyr**, separating at the "_":

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(data, cols=everything(), names_sep="_",
             names_to=c("Question","Case"))

# A tibble: 194 x 3
   Question Case  value
   <chr>    <chr> <int>
 1 Q2       1         5
 2 Q2       2         5
 3 Q5       1         1
 4 Q5       2         2
 5 Q6       1         4
 6 Q6       2         4
 7 Q9       1         4
 8 Q9       2         4
 9 Q11      1         5
10 Q11      2         3
# ... with 184 more rows
```

---

Attempt to use the `reshape` function results in an error due to inconsistent variable names in the wide format. For example, as you mentioned, some names have an additional ".1", which you say is irrelevant. The **tidyr** package agrees because it just gathers everything after the separator and puts whatever it finds into the "Case" variable (the second item in the `names_to` argument). The `reshape` function is more strict. That is, the additional ".1" is *not* irrelevant (according to the function) because the function will attempt to guess the values contained in the names (after the "_"), sees that the lengths are unequal, and fails with `'varying' arguments must be the same length`.

An alternative using `sep=""` is given below...

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to reshape just on one category "question" (i.e. not on more categories as e.g. "question" and "year"), all the `Q*` variables can be considered as unique (sub-)questions.

Hence you may want to `sep`arate by `""`,

```
tmp <- reshape(dat[-1], varying=1:194, direction="long", sep="")
```

which and gives you a long format with `time` variable including all the sub questions.

```
head(tmp, 3)
#       time Q id
# 1.2_1  2_1 5  1
# 1.2_2  2_2 5  1
# 1.5_1  5_1 1  1
```

Thereafter you simply may split the `time` variable at `"_"` using `strsplit`, give the result nice names using `setNames`, and order it.

```
res <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp$time, "_")), tmp[2:3],
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
                c("question", "case", "value", "id"))
res <- res[order(as.numeric(res$question)), ]
```

### Result

```
head(res, 18)
#          question case value id
# 1.2_1           2    1     5  1
# 1.2_2           2    2     5  1
# 1.5_1           5    1     1  1
# 1.5_2           5    2     2  1
# 1.6_1           6    1     4  1
# 1.6_2           6    2     4  1
# 1.8_1           8    1     5  1
# 1.8_2           8    2     3  1
# 1.9_1           9    1     4  1
# 1.9_2           9    2     4  1
# 1.10_1         10    1     5  1
# 1.10_2         10    2     4  1
# 1.11_1         11    1     5  1
# 1.11_2         11    2     3  1
# 1.11_1.1       11  1.1     5  1
# 1.11_2.1       11  2.1     4  1
# 1.14_1         14    1     3  1
# 1.14_2         14    2     2  1
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(X = 2L, Q2_1 = 5L, Q2_2 = 5L, Q5_1 = 1L, Q5_2 = 2L, 
    Q6_1 = 4L, Q6_2 = 4L, Q9_1 = 4L, Q9_2 = 4L, Q11_1 = 5L, Q11_2 = 3L, 
    Q8_1 = 5L, Q8_2 = 3L, Q14_1 = 3L, Q14_2 = 2L, Q16_1 = 5L, 
    Q16_2 = 4L, Q10_1 = 5L, Q10_2 = 4L, Q11_1.1 = 5L, Q11_2.1 = 4L, 
    Q19_1 = 5L, Q19_2 = 5L, Q20_1 = 5L, Q20_2 = 5L, Q21_1 = 5L, 
    Q21_2 = 5L, Q15_1 = 5L, Q15_2 = 5L, Q23_1 = 5L, Q23_2 = 4L, 
    Q24_1 = 5L, Q24_2 = 5L, Q25_1 = 5L, Q25_2 = 5L, Q26_1 = 4L, 
    Q26_2 = 5L, Q20_1.1 = 4L, Q20_2.1 = 5L, Q21_1.1 = 4L, Q21_2.1 = 5L, 
    Q29_1 = 5L, Q29_2 = 5L, Q30_1 = 5L, Q30_2 = 5L, Q35_1 = 4L, 
    Q35_2 = 5L, Q36_1 = 5L, Q36_2 = 5L, Q37_1 = 5L, Q37_2 = 5L, 
    Q38_1 = 5L, Q38_2 = 5L, Q39_1 = 5L, Q39_2 = 5L, Q41_1 = 5L, 
    Q41_2 = 5L, Q30_1.1 = 5L, Q30_2.1 = 5L, Q43_1 = 5L, Q43_2 = 5L, 
    Q44_1 = 5L, Q44_2 = 5L, Q45_1 = 5L, Q45_2 = 5L, Q47_1 = 5L, 
    Q47_2 = 5L, Q48_1 = 5L, Q48_2 = 5L, Q36_1.1 = 4L, Q36_2.1 = 5L, 
    Q37_1.1 = 5L, Q37_2.1 = 5L, Q51_1 = 3L, Q51_2 = 2L, Q52_1 = 3L, 
    Q52_2 = 2L, Q53_1 = 3L, Q53_2 = 2L, Q41_1.1 = 3L, Q41_2.1 = 2L, 
    Q42_1 = 3L, Q42_2 = 2L, Q56_1 = 5L, Q56_2 = 5L, Q57_1 = 5L, 
    Q57_2 = 5L, Q58_1 = 5L, Q58_2 = 5L, Q59_1 = 3L, Q59_2 = 2L, 
    Q60_1 = 4L, Q60_2 = 2L, Q61_1 = 3L, Q61_2 = 2L, Q62_1 = 3L, 
    Q62_2 = 2L, Q63_1 = 5L, Q63_2 = 4L, Q64_1 = 5L, Q64_2 = 4L, 
    Q65_1 = 5L, Q65_2 = 5L, Q53_1.1 = 5L, Q53_2.1 = 5L, Q54_1 = 3L, 
    Q54_2 = 2L, Q68_1 = 5L, Q68_2 = 4L, Q75_1 = 4L, Q75_2 = 4L, 
    Q57_1.1 = 4L, Q57_2.1 = 4L, Q58_1.1 = 3L, Q58_2.1 = 2L, Q59_1.1 = 5L, 
    Q59_2.1 = 5L, Q60_1.1 = 5L, Q60_2.1 = 5L, Q61_1.1 = 4L, Q61_2.1 = 3L, 
    Q81_1 = 5L, Q81_2 = 5L, Q82_1 = 5L, Q82_2 = 5L, Q83_1 = 5L, 
    Q83_2 = 5L, Q87_1 = 5L, Q87_2 = 5L, Q88_1 = 5L, Q88_2 = 5L, 
    Q89_1 = 5L, Q89_2 = 5L, Q90_1 = 4L, Q90_2 = 4L, Q91_1 = 5L, 
    Q91_2 = 5L, Q92_1 = 5L, Q92_2 = 5L, Q93_1 = 5L, Q93_2 = 5L, 
    Q94_1 = 5L, Q94_2 = 5L, Q95_1 = 5L, Q95_2 = 5L, Q74_1 = 5L, 
    Q74_2 = 5L, Q75_1.1 = 5L, Q75_2.1 = 5L, Q76_1 = 5L, Q76_2 = 5L, 
    Q77_1 = 5L, Q77_2 = 5L, Q100_1 = 5L, Q100_2 = 5L, Q101_1 = 5L, 
    Q101_2 = 5L, Q102_1 = 5L, Q102_2 = 5L, Q103_1 = 5L, Q103_2 = 5L, 
    Q104_1 = 5L, Q104_2 = 5L, Q105_1 = 5L, Q105_2 = 5L, Q106_1 = 5L, 
    Q106_2 = 5L, Q107_1 = 5L, Q107_2 = 5L, Q108_1 = 5L, Q108_2 = 5L, 
    Q113_1 = 5L, Q113_2 = 5L, Q114_1 = 4L, Q114_2 = 4L, Q117_1 = 5L, 
    Q117_2 = 5L, Q96_1 = 5L, Q96_2 = 5L, Q97_1 = 5L, Q97_2 = 5L, 
    Q98_1 = 5L, Q98_2 = 5L, Q121_1 = 5L, Q121_2 = 5L, Q103_1.1 = 5L, 
    Q103_2.1 = 5L, Q104_1.1 = 5L, Q104_2.1 = 5L, Q127_1 = 4L, 
    Q127_2 = 4L, Q128_1 = 5L, Q128_2 = 5L, Q129_1 = 4L, Q129_2 = 4L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```